# \includegraphics{*.pdf } substitutes in-figure symbols

Tags: graphics, symbols, pdf, eps

I am using TeXstudio with its default settings. My figure is saved as PDF because I was unable to include `*.eps` because of the `Unknown graphics extension: .eps`-error. The figure opens without faults in Adobe Illustrator, however when I use `\includegraphics{*.pdf }`, the `pi` symbol on one of the axes of the figure is converted to the `unequal` symbol.

That looks pathetic!

How do I proceed to be able to include my figure correctly?

```
\documentclass[final]{report}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}.}

% Title Page
\title{Første obligatoriske øvelse MEK1100 vår 2013}
\author{Marius Jonsson}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\section{Skalering}
\subsection{}


\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{skudd.pdf}
\caption{Prosjektilbaner for utgangsvinkler $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{4}$ og $\frac{\pi}{3}$}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I cannot find anythign wrong with the file. Perhaps you can? It views fine in my other software. As requested: here is the file "skudd.pdf": http://www.kingoslo.com/temp/skudd.pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!]([Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: To be able to compile your MWE you should provide a link to the file `skudd.pdf`, which in addition looks as the main suspect in your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with JLDiaz - the file skudd.pdf is probably at fault, most probably because a font is not included in the file, or the font encoding is broken or not included.  If it views OK in a pdf previewer, try printing-to-pdf from that, or use some other method to do a pdf-ps-pdf round-trip.  ... and good luck with the first assignment.  (Hopefully the exercise wasn't solely to fix a broken pdf inclusion.)

Comment: Font isn't embedded when exporting from matlab. You are right.M